# Java Menu Using Do while loop keeps repeating

Tags: java, loops

This code should display a menu and afterwards it should give the user the possibility to choose from the menu. The user can choose 3 items along with the quantity and afterwards the total price is displayed and the program stops.
This is what the program should look like when it runs:

```
This is the menu for Tal'Qroq Restourant:


This is the menu of pizzas

A.Margherita ..... $5.50
B.Capricosa ..... $6.50
C.Funghi ..... $7.00
D.Vegeterian..... $7.00
E.Tropical..... $8.00
F.Meat ..... $8.00
G.Salami..... $8.00
H.Maltija..... $8.00
I.Calzona..... $8.50
J.Tal'Qroq special..... $8.00 

Enter your pizza order according to the menu letters:
```

After the user inputs the pizza the quantity is asked and that works fine.
The user must be asked 3 times to enter the pizza and quantity but instead the loop wont stop and keep asking and asking infinitely and this is my problem!
The following is the code:

```
public class Menu{
    public static void main (String[]args){

    float total = 0;
    char cas = 0;
    int quant = 0;
    int count = 0;

    System.out.println("This is the menu for Tal'Qroq Restourant:");
    System.out.println("\n");
    System.out.println("This is the menu of pizzas");
    System.out.println("\n");
    System.out.println("A.Margherita ..... $5.50");
    System.out.println("\n");
    System.out.println("B.Capricosa ..... $6.50");
    System.out.println("\n");
    System.out.println("C.Funghi ..... $7.00");
    System.out.println("\n");
    System.out.println("D.Vegeterian..... $7.00");
    System.out.println("\n");
    System.out.println("E.Tropical..... $8.00");
    System.out.println("\n");
    System.out.println("F.Meat ..... $8.00");
    System.out.println("\n");
    System.out.println("G.Salami..... $8.00");
    System.out.println("\n");
    System.out.println("H.Maltija..... $8.00");
    System.out.println("\n");
    System.out.println("I.Calzona..... $8.50");
    System.out.println("\n");
    System.out.println("J.Tal'Qroq special..... $8.00");
    System.out.println("\n");

    float a = 5.50f;
    float b = 6.50f;
    float c = 7.00f;
    float d = 7.00f;
    float e = 8.00f;
    float f = 8.00f;
    float g = 8.00f;
    float h = 8.00f;
    float i = 8.00f;
    float j = 8.00f;


    do{
        System.out.print("Enter your pizza order according to the menu letters: ");
        cas = Keyboard.readChar(); 

        System.out.print("Enter the ammount of pizza you want: ");
        quant = Keyboard.readInt();

         if(cas == 'a' || cas == 'A'){
        System.out.println("Total for " + quant + " Margherita is :" + (a*quant));
        System.out.println("\n");
        total = total + (a*quant);
        count = count++;

        }else if(cas == 'b' || cas == 'B'){
            System.out.println("Total for " + quant + " Capricosa is :" + (b*quant));
            System.out.println("\n");
            total = total + (b*quant);
            count = count++;

        }else if(cas == 'c' || cas == 'C'){
            System.out.println("Total for " + quant + " Funghi is :" + (c*quant));
            System.out.println("\n");
            total = total + (c*quant);  
            count = count++;

        }else if(cas == 'd' || cas == 'D'){
            System.out.println("Total for " + quant + " Vegeterian is :" + (d*quant));
            System.out.println("\n");
            total = total + (d*quant);
            count = count++;

        }else if(cas == 'e' || cas == 'E'){
            System.out.println("Total for " + quant +  " Tropical is :" + (e*quant));
            System.out.println("\n");
            total = total + (e*quant);
            count = count++;

        }else if(cas == 'f' || cas == 'F'){
            System.out.println("Total for " + quant + " Meat is :" + (f*quant));
            System.out.println("\n");
            total = total + (f*quant);
            count = count++;

        }else if(cas == 'g' || cas == 'G'){
            System.out.println("Total for " + quant + " Salami is :" + (g*quant));
            System.out.println("\n");
            total = total + (g*quant);
            count = count++;

        }else if(cas == 'h' || cas == 'H'){
            System.out.println("Total for " + quant + " Calzona is :" + (h*quant));
            System.out.println("\n");
            total = total + (h*quant);
            count = count++;

        }else if(cas == 'i' || cas == 'I'){
           System.out.println("Total for " + quant + " Maltija is :" + (i*quant));
           System.out.println("\n");
           total = total + (i*quant);
           count = count++;

        }else if(cas == 'j' || cas == 'J'){
           System.out.println("Total for " + quant + " Tal'Qroq special is :" + (j*quant));
           System.out.println("\n");
           total = total + (j*quant);
           count = count++;
        }else{
        System.out.println("Your selection isn't avaliable in our Menu!");
        System.out.println("\n");
    }    
    } while (count <= 3);
    System.out.println("Your total is €" + total);
}
```

}

Any answers or help is highly appreciated :).

Comment: What is the input you are providing? It seems that count is not always augmented. make the count++ statement the last statement of the while block (don'ty repeat it everywhere), and make sure it applies to all possibilities EDIT - Also, use switch case statements instead of if-else structures here. It'll make your code a lot easier to read

Comment: Just a mark: your string comparison in conditions is done wrong, use equals() and toLowerCase() to avoid OR in condition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your statement `count = count++` looks wrong. Use just `count++` or `count = count + 1`.

Using `count = count++` creates byte code somewhat like this:

```
 temp = count
 count = count + 1
 count = temp
```

So in effect the count is not getting incremented.

Using `count = ++count` should work, but logically looks wrong:

```
count = count + 1
count = count
```

Best not try the *funny characteristic* of compilers.

Comment: Think you nailed it. The value being assigned before the temporary value (which isn't stored) is set. hmmm, missed that.

Comment: Or `count = ++count;` but `count++;` is the best option.

Answer (score 0):

```
int i = 1;
i = i++;
System.out.prinln(i); //-> 1
```

You just have to write "i++;" and then you are good.

And btw. Never Ever save money in a float or a double ;)

Edit:

```
int i = 1;
i = ++i;
```

That would be possible because you are increasing i before you assign the new value.

Answer (score 0):

You have several things that you could improve in your program. First, let's get to the bug, you are saying `count = count ++` but by doing this, the compiler will start by incrementing the value of count, and then revert count to its old value, since `count++` will be returning not the incremented value. To simplify, this statement does nothing, and do not increment the value of `count`.

When you want to increment, use the postfix operator:
`count++`;

By analysing your program, you can notice a lot of duplicate code that could be reduced!

For example, when comparing the inputs, you can use `.equals()`, this way you don't have to split the case for upper and lowercase:

```
(cas == 'f' || cas == 'F')
```

is equivalent to

```
cas.equals('f')
```

Which you can repeat for the rest of the cases.

Inside each if statement, you are doing the same `system.out.println`. For simplicity you can declare a variable for print, like

```
String typeofPizza;
```

And then inside each `if`

```
typeofPizza = "Margherita";
```

This way, you can remove the print to the end of the `if`clauses:

```
System.out.println("Total for " + quant + typeofPizza + "is :" + total);
```

Comment: `(cas == 'f' || cas == 'F')` is **not** equivalent to `cas.equals('f')`! You probably meant: `cas.equalsIgnoreCase('f')`, didn't you?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your early responses :).The program worked fine. I can't believe a made such a stupid mistake `count ++` instead of `++ count`.I also had the change int count to ***1*** instead of ***0***.